# Best way to store application properties in Storage Extension

Tags: web8.5, storage-extensions

Currently I have a Storage Extension for SDL Web 8.5 (I extended from 'JPABinaryContentDAO' and implemented 'BinaryContentDAO'). I have some settings hard-coded in the Java code, which are environment specific.

What is the best-practice to store and retrieve values from config files in this case?

The constructors do not contain any reference to the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my answer on: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-a-configuration-file-for-your-custom-tridion-content-delivery-code.

```
public MyStorageExtension(String storageId, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, EntityManager entityManager, String storageName) throws ConfigurationException
{
    super(storageId, entityManagerFactory, entityManager, storageName);
    configuration = new XMLConfigurationReader().readConfiguration("settings.xml"); //create this file in the config directory of the deployer
    String s = ConfigurationHelper.getStringValue(configuration, "/appSettings/endpoint", "DEFAULT FALLBACK STRING VALUE");

}
```

That's all.